# SQL multiple tables and display if no record

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have 4 tables (workers, group, department, office) and would like to have a single SQL query that would return a report (report).

```
    Table: Workers
    +------------+----------+--------------+
    | workers_id | group_id | workers_name |
    +------------+----------+--------------+

    Table: Group
    +------------+------------+---------+-----------+
    | group_id   | group_name | dept_id | office_id |
    +------------+------------+---------+-----------+

    Table: Department
    +---------+----------+-----------+
    | dept_id | dept_name| office_id |
    +---------+----------+-----------+

    Table: Office
    +-----------+------------+
    | office_id | office_name|
    +-----------+------------+
```

I have managed to use the following SQL statement that would give me Result A:

```
    SELECT department.dept_name, count (workers.workers_id) as headcount,
    FROM workers, group, department
    WHERE workers.workers_id = group.group_id
    AND group.dept_id = department.dept_id
    GROUP BY group.group_id

    Result A: 
    +------------+----------+
    | dept_name  | headcount|
    +------------+----------+
    | dept A     | 2        |
    +------------+----------+
    | dept B     | 1        |
    +------------+----------+
    | dept D     | 2        |
    +------------+----------+
    | dept F     | 3        |
    +------------+----------+
```

However its not listing department with 0 number of workers (made sense because there arent any). Is it possible to still do a single query to have the following result?

```
    Result: 
    +------------+----------+
    | dept_name  | headcount|
    +------------+----------+
    | dept A     | 2        |
    +------------+----------+
    | dept B     | 1        |
    +------------+----------+
    | dept C     | 0        |
    +------------+----------+
    | dept D     | 2        |
    +------------+----------+
    | dept E     | 0        |
    +------------+----------+
    | dept F     | 3        |
    +------------+----------+
```

I've experimented with isnull, left join and union without any luck, my sql-fu is at basic level. Would appreciate any help with this. Cheers!

Comment: Tip of today: switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax - easier to write (without errors), easier to read, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: This isn't your query :-(

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid. Will raise an error on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode), and return unpredictable data with older versions. The general GROUP BY rule says: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Comment: That's not your query, you have a sintax error in **as headcount,** you have a semicolon. Don't give a table the name GROUP, you will get a mess with the GROUP BY

Comment: @nacho _sintax_ ... where bad code becomes morally reprehensible :-)

Comment: `WHERE workers.workers_id = group.group_id`. Was it intended?

Comment: oh silly me, things got lost in translation (original table name was in my native language). forgot GROUP is a reserve word. Thanks jarlh & nacho. Also, it should be GROUP BY (department.dept_id), as spotted by Batsu & perhaps Strawberry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following query is what you want.  You can retain every department in your result set, even if it have no head count, by doing a left join from the department table to a subquery which finds headcount by department, if that department exists.

```
SELECT
    d.dept_id,
    d.dept_name,
    d.office_id,
    COALESCE(t.cnt, 0) AS headcount
FROM Department d
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT t1.dept_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM `Group` t1
    INNER JOIN Workers t2
        ON t1.group_id = t2.group_id
    GROUP BY t1.dept_id
) t
    ON d.dept_id = t.dept_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the workers for department I think you mean to group by `dept_id` (otherwise the `COUNT` will count the worker by group, not dept. This will lead to incorrect results when there is more than one group in a dept). Also I guess the join on `workers.workers_id = group.group_id` wasn't intended:

```
SELECT d.dept_name, COUNT(w.workers_id) AS headcount
    FROM Workers w
      JOIN Grp g ON w.group_id = g.group_id
      RIGHT JOIN Department d ON g.dept_id = d.dept_id
    GROUP BY d.dept_id;
```

`NULL` *workers_id*s won't be taken into account in the `COUNT`.

Note: don't name a table like keywords (`GROUP`).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT dept_name,
IF(count(workers_id) >0 ,count(*),0) AS headcount
FROM workers, group, department
WHERE workers.workers_id = group.group_id
AND group.dept_id = department.dept_id
GROUP BY group.group_id;
```

You can use IF statement,
syntax of IF statement is..

IF(Condetion,result if true,result if false)

Comment: I have modified your SQL to fix my initial error (i.e. using reserve word GROUP and the grouping by dept). Its giving me my result A, so the IF does not work to show the department without workers